# Select Cells of one Page in a Print Area

Tags: vba, excel, page-break

I have a workbook with several worksheets with Print Areas defined.  Each print area has 0 or more page breaks defined.  How would one go about selecting just the cells in Page 1 only or the cells in page 2 only of the print area.  I have written code to select page 1:

```
Dim wksht As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim prntArea As Range
Set wksht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set prntArea = wksht.Range(wksht.PageSetup.printArea)
'Select Page 1 of print area
'First cell of print area
Set rng = prntArea.Cells(1, 1)
'extend to one row above page break
Set rng = wksht.Range(rng.Address, wksht.HPageBreaks(1).Location.Offset(-1).Address)
'extend to last column of Print Area
Set rng = wksht.Range(rng.Address, wksht.Cells(prntArea.Cells(1, 1).Row, prntArea.Cells(prntArea.Count).Column).Address)
rng.Copy
```

Then I would have to write more code for selecting a second and third page if they exist, going from one page break to the next or the end of the print area.

Is there an easier way to select just one of the pages of the print area?

What I am trying to do:

The user can print to PDF currently using ExportToFixedFormat, and that uses the print areas.  They want to be able to print to PowerPoint and Word.  So, I am creating a new PowerPoint Presentation and selecting the print page areas, then copy and paste into new slide.  I have everything working, except trying to find an easier way to select the print pages.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `Worksheet.VPageBreaks` (vertical pagebreaks) and `Worksheet.HPageBreaks` (horiz pagebreaks) collection properties as you realised. However, I would suggest you use an approach similar to the below rather than assuming the printarea is always 1 page wide).

You can analyse them to identify the areas covered by each page.

The below code shows some ways to work with and interact with them. Have a look at the their methods and properties, in particular the Location property. Look at the debug text (make sure you have the Immediates window visible) to see how the .Locations correspond to the pagebreaks you can see on the page.

```
Sub PageBreaksExample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim hpb As HPageBreak
    Dim vpb As VPageBreak

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each hpb In ws.HPageBreaks
        Debug.Print "Horizontal pagebreak: " & hpb.Location.Address
    Next hpb

    For Each vpb In ws.VPageBreaks
        Debug.Print "Vertical pagebreak:" & vpb.Location.Address
    Next vpb

    'You can get the first page range like: (adjust for second page etc)
    Dim rng
    Set rng = ws.Range( _
        ws.HPageBreaks(1).Location.Offset(-1, 0), _
        ws.VPageBreaks(1).Location.Offset(0, -1))
    Debug.Print "Range of first page:" & rng.Address

End Sub
```

Note that the first page is always found by looking at HPageBreaks(1) and VPageBreaks(1). However, depending on how the worksheet is set to print subsequent pages (down then over vs over then down) affects how you should find the second and onwards pages. You can identify which way it is going by looking at `Worksheet.PageSetup.Order` property (`xlDownThenOver` or `xlOverThenDown`).

Answer (score 0):

This is ultimately what I have come up with to this issue.  This will only work with horizontal page breaks.  It is divided into 3 sections.  First is when there are no page breaks, and only one page to print.  The second is when there is one page break, and two pages to print.  Then the third section is for 2 or more page breaks, meaning there are 3 or more pages.  Where you see *******Work on Selected Range**, that means the rng contains the page for the print area, this is where you want to perform action on the page of the print area.

```
Dim wksht as Worksheet
For Each wksht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Dim prntArea As Range
    Set prntArea = wksht.Range(wksht.PageSetup.printArea)


    If wksht.HPageBreaks.Count = 0 Then 'No Page Breaks in Print Area
        Set rng = prntArea
        '*****Work on selected range
    End If


    If wksht.HPageBreaks.Count = 1 Then 'One Page Break = 2 Pages
        ' Page 1
        Set rng = prntArea.Cells(1, 1)
        Set rng = wksht.Range(rng.Address, wksht.HPageBreaks(1).Location.Offset(-1).Address)
        Set rng = Application.Intersect(rng.EntireRow, prntArea)
        '*****Work on Selected Range

        ' Page 2
        Set rng = wksht.Range(wksht.HPageBreaks(1).Location.Address, prntArea.Cells(prntArea.Rows.Count, 1))
        Set rng = Application.Intersect(rng.EntireRow, prntArea)
        '*****Work on selected Range
    End If


    If wksht.HPageBreaks.Count > 1 Then   '2 or more Page Breaks = 3 or more pages
        ' Page 1
        Set rng = prntArea.Cells(1, 1)
        Set rng = wksht.Range(rng.Address, wksht.HPageBreaks(1).Location.Offset(-1).Address)
        Set rng = wksht.Range(rng.Address, wksht.Cells(prntArea.Cells(1, 1).Row, prntArea.Cells(prntArea.Count).Column).Address)
        '*****Work on Selected Range

        ' Pages 2 through (pages - 1)
        Dim pgBreaks As Integer
        For pgBreaks = 1 To wksht.HPageBreaks.Count - 1
            Set rng = wksht.Range(wksht.HPageBreaks(pgBreaks).Location.Address, wksht.HPageBreaks(pgBreaks + 1).Location.Offset(-1).Address)
            If rng.Columns.Count < prntArea.Columns.Count Then
                Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count, prntArea.Columns.Count)
            End If
            '*****Work on Selected Range
        Next pgBreaks

        'Last Page
        Set rng = wksht.Range(wksht.HPageBreaks(wksht.HPageBreaks.Count).Location.Address, prntArea.Cells(prntArea.Rows.Count, 1))
        Set rng = Application.Intersect(rng.EntireRow, prntArea)
        '*****Work on Selected Range
    End If
Next wksht
```

Answer (score -2):

I need Table of content with one excel sheet based on after page break  heading text/page number as a link for the page navigation

Comment: Is this an answer to this question?